# ImportError: No module named NetCDF

Tags: c++, python, netcdf

I am trying to sort the following error but not getting the correct answer till now. Actually I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and I have installed netcdf-3.6.2 but even then i found this error, although I added the header like

```
import Scientific.IO.NetCDF
from Numeric import * 
from NetCDF import *
```

But it does not make any impact and shows the following error:

> ImportError: No module named NetCDF

Answer (score 0):

If the module is `Scientific.IO.NetCDF`, then you need to do `from Scientific.IO.NetCDF import *` (and you don't need to do `import Scientific.IO.NetCDF` first). Also, importing everything is often a bad style, and should be avoided.